# Newly installed program does not launch from dash

Tags: 14.04, launcher, unity-dash, .desktop

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04, and installed a .deb file I downloaded (so install happens through Software Center). (Almost) All went well, and the program icon appeared in the Dash.

When clicking it, nothing happens however. I *can* launch the program by typing its name in the commandline. I can also lock the program icon to the launcher once it runs, and launch it from there. That is however not what I want; I'd like to keep the launcher minimal.

This happens both with the Vivaldi browser and the Git Kraken tool. (So I guess it's not the program causing this.) Restarting does not solve the problem. Any hints appreciated.

Comment: Hi Johan, you mention:  *I can lock the program icn to the launcher and launch it from there*. In that case, did you lock the *running application* to the launcher, or did you drag its launcher on to the Unity Launcher?

Comment: Jacob,I locked the running program.

Comment: Thanks, I am on mobile, will answer tonight if I get home :)

Comment: Yes I did, Jacob, very late yesterday. Only just now I have the time to try your solution. I'll keep you informed.

Comment: Johan, I am starting to believe there is something wrong with your Unity.  The launcher(s) seem not to be listed in Unity somehow. I will remove my answer, since my assumptio was incorrect. Never ran into this before.

Comment: Could the person who's answer was questioned by Jacob Vlijm repost pls?